# is there css selector query for every element inside div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply style for every thing inside div

example :

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <h1>...</h1>
     <p>...</p>
     <img ... />
     <div>
       <a>...</a>
       <a>...</a>
     </div>
     <button>...<button>
<div>
```

css :

```
#myDiv {
   padding : 5px;
   color : #2B2B2B;
   font-weight : 700;
}
```

I want all element inside the div to have same style as div

the query I'm looking for is something like this `#div  , #div MY_ALL_ELEMENTS`

maybe this dumb question , but I'm newbie to `css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a [universal selector `*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). For all *direct* discendants, use the [child combinator `#div > *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, that selector would be `#myDiv * { ... }`, which selects ALL elements inside `#myDiv`(not only the direct children elements, but also children of children etc.)

```css
#myDiv * {
   padding : 5px;
   color : #2B2B2B;
   font-weight : 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
     <h1>bla</h1>
     <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
     <img bla />
     <div>
       <a>bla  bla </a>
       <a>bla bla bla</a>
     </div>
     <button>bla</button>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use universal selector

```
#myDev , #myDev * 
{
    ...
}
```